# Laravel file Manager url was not found?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ckeditor, tinymce

I use laravel file manager package with tinymce

I try to installation same as document https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/installation

and setting javascript same as document https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/integration

But when i click icon the error show

```
 The requested URL /laravel-filemanager was not found on this server.
```

- I try to php artisan r:l and yes! I already have url laravel-filemanager

  |GET|HEAD| laravel-filemanager | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\LfmController@show
- I already clear all cache in config,app,route still didn't work

I set up path in javascript

```
 path_absolute : "/",
```

In lfm.php file

```
 'base_directory' => 'public',
```

Comment: what happens if you change the URLS from `/laravel-filemanager` to `laravel-filemanager`?

Comment: it' said Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. @Loek

Comment: That's progress I guess? Is it a true 404, or does laravel not understand the URL?

Comment: when i enter url /public/laravel-filemanager well, It said error:Type error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector::singularize() must be of the type string . In this error it prove that I alredy have this to route .